# draw an inclined line in assembly

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

i need to draw an inclined line in assembly using emulator 8086 where the row value is stored in `dx`  and the column in `cx` so i compare the initial value of both by the final value but it doesn't work correctly as is stops when it reaches only the column final value or the row not both which is required
this is the part of the code that is supposed to draw the line

```
u4: mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel
    int 10h

 cmp dx,50
 dec dx
 dec cx
 cmp cx,[1000h]
 ja u4
```

Comment: The result of the first `cmp` is never used. You need a conditional jump there too.

Comment: I don't know if you're restricted to using `int 10h`, as opposed to say, mode 13h, but there's a lot of code around for keywords like [Bresenham + BIOS](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=bresenham+bios).

Comment: when i put another jump after the first cmp it just reaches the final row and neglect the second cmp i cant figure out how to solve this

Comment: •Specify a color attribute in AL (e.g 1 for blue)
•Make sure that you use the vide mode. Use the command
"mov ah, 0"
"mov al, (videomode)"
"int 10h"
to set your computer into video mode
(for example mode 19 is 320x200 with 256 colors)

Comment: @vanUitkon i used all this in the main code-which draws a trapezoid- this is only a small part which is responsible for the inclined line.

Comment: Have you set cx and dx in your main code?

Answer (score 0):

```
 mov cx, 204  ; column
    mov dx, 1     ; row
    mov al, 15     ; white
u1: mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
    int 10h

    dec cx
    cmp cx, 1
    jae u1
```

Try this one it should display an upper line. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

```
    mov cx, 204  ; column
    mov dx, 1     ; row
    mov al, 15     ; white
u1: mov ah, 0ch     ; put pixel

int 10h

    dec cx
    cmp cx, 1
    jae u1
```

this should do copy from mov cx upto jae u1 hope it will help